# Output of Stored procedure to Temp table at runtime

Tags: sql-server, openrowset

I have a procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getdata
AS
SELECT *
FROM mytable
```

Now i want insert the output into a temporary table. I can do like

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable
EXEC getdata
```

But i have to create a table beforehand for this. How can I achieve something like below (without creating table before)

```
select * into #temp exec getdata
```

I have tried with `openrowset`

```
SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
'EXEC getdata')
```

but unfortunately i'm getting `enable ad hoc distributed queries` error and i cannot currently request for the access. Is there any alternate method to achieve this?

Comment: You can't. The syntax is `SELECT ... INTO` not `EXEC ... INTO`. To insert the results of an `SP` into a table using `EXEC` you **must** create it first. Shouldn't you know the definition of the table coming back anyway, so you can easily create it? I *assume* your SP isn't as simple as `SELECT * FROM MyTable` as otherwise I don't really see the need of the SP.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu for the comment.  I tried to create a table dynamically inside my procedure. But that is not accessible outside?

Comment: If you create a table inside an SP that's inside the same scope, it'll still be accessible outside of the SP. Why were you trying to create a table dynamically though? I feel like you're not telling us the full story here. YOur SP is just `SELECT * FROM MyTable` there's nothign dynamic there, and the definition of the table is fixed.

Comment: You are right. My `select` is not that simple. Just for sample I have put `*`. But even the Columns are dynamic. @Larnu

Comment: If you use dynamic SQL to create the local temp table it will be dropped as soon as the dynamic SQL exits. Not impossible though you can do `CREATE TABLE #Foo(Dummy_column int);` and then generate dynamic `ALTER TABLE` to add the columns per the result of `EXEC sys.sp_describe_first_result_set N'EXEC getdata'` and then drop the dummy column. This is left as an exercise for you though. Does seem like a dubious requirement

Comment: Erland has extensive discussion of [sharing data between procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) which also includes this <insert ... exec> approach. Perhaps you should reconsider the decisions that lead to this path. Applying the <insert into temptable> pattern is often not needed and frequently inefficient.